# Save as pdf in print window javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf, printing

HELP.. how to Save as pdf in print window in javascript code

How to change this code ?

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">PDF</a>
```

I need to make my link open the print window but automatically set the destination to "Save as pdf" instead of "print"?

Comment: Impossible, that is user action and not all users have "save as PDF" as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this via javascript.

You can do this:

```
<a href="/getpdf.php">PDF</a>
```

In getpdf form pdf file via TCPDF or other